# What are some songs About dentists or visiting the dentist?

Tags: genre, similar-artists

My dentist challenged me to bring in a **playlist of songs about going to the dentist** on my next appointment. I've looked for songs, but haven't found that many.
Here's what I have so far:
[image: Dental Care by Owl City, It's Dentist Time Again by Nick Cope, Dentist Song by Galahad, The Dentist by Bryant Oden, Dentist Song by Eb Eberlein, The Dentist Song by Mike Aussem, The Dentist Song by Rob Disner, I have a hole in my tooth by dodie]

"Dentist" doesn't have to be in the name, but some aspect of dental work or dental hygiene should probably be in the lyrics somewhere. I don't need songs for little kids such as "Brush Your Teeth with Elmo" or anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but 'listening recommendation' questions are off topic. Just to throw you a bone, though - Alice Cooper, Unfinished Sweet, 1973. "Your teeth are OK, but your gums gotta go." Complete with drill noises & a 'nearly James Bond' instrumental. I have the instrumental section as my own dentist's ringtone ;))

Comment: Thanks. would you say there is a better place to post this? Reddit and Instagram haven't been of much help.

Comment: Not anywhere on SE, no. If anywhere I'd have thought Reddit, Instagram, Facebook etc would have been your best bet

Comment: Yeah, been through that. I've been trying to leverage other sites that do lyric searches or something like that. Think I have doubled my playlist since asking around, so that's at least pretty good.

Comment: Not sure if it counts, but 1990s Euro/dance artist Dr Alban is a real dentist. I don't think he wrote any dentist-themed songs however.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

There's a song about a dentist in the soundtrack to the musical version of '[Little Shop of Horrors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091419/)'

> ORIN:
> When I was younger, just a bad little kid
> My mama noticed funny things I did
> Like shootin' puppies with a BB gun
> I'd poison guppies, and when I was done
> I'd find a pussycat and bash in its head
> That's when my mama said

> CRYSTAL, RONETTE, CHIFFON:
> What did she say?

> ORIN:
> She said, "My boy, I think someday
> You'll find a way
> To make your natural tendencies pay
> You'll be a dentist

> CRYSTAL, RONETTE, CHIFFON:
> You'll be a dentist

[Dentist song](https://littleshop.fandom.com/wiki/Dentist!)

Comment: Thanks! That works!